# Reading from RS 232 port using python

Tags: python, serial-port

I want to write a program in python for reading from RS 232 port.
My laptop doesn't have this port.
Can anyone suggest any good simulator for the same and a sample python program for reading from RS 232 port.

Comment: You can get a cheap USB-RS-232 dongle for a few $ and use that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I got the solution. I used a Virtual serial port simulator to create virtual 2 ports and I paired those ports. Then I used pyserial python library for reading from and writing to the ports.
**Sample code for reading from port**

```
import time
import serial

# configure the serial connections (the parameters differs on the device you are connecting to)
ser = serial.Serial(
    port='COM2',
    baudrate=9600,
    timeout=1,
    parity=serial.PARITY_ODD,
    stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_TWO,
    bytesize=serial.SEVENBITS
)
ser.isOpen()
# Reading the data from the serial port. This will be running in an infinite loop.

while 1 :
        # get keyboard input
        bytesToRead = ser.inWaiting()
        data = ser.read(bytesToRead)
        time.sleep(1)
        print(data)
```