# how can i read rs232 serial data in laravel 9?

Tags: php, laravel, serial-port

I would like to retrieve data from the RS232 port in which I connected a scale to retrieve real-time data in laravel, and also connected a printer with laravel

Comment: Firstly, this can only be done for data on the serial port on the server machine, not the client machine. The how depends on the operating system. For Linux for example the serial port seems to be outputting to something like `/dev/ttyS0` so if you open this in a read stream you should be able to read all data as they are available.

Comment: Anything is possible, but if you need help with this you need to expand your question quite a bit. What is your setup exactly? Hardware, OS, browser, etc. What have you tried so far? Why didn't that work? What is your real problem here?

Comment: I would just like to recover it the operating system is Windows development environment is Laravel 9 with Vue 3

Comment: **One of the ways**: Simply write a console application (say in C, python, etc. ) reading the RS232 port and then feed the captured data to the laravel system for further processing. For reference you may read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23534506/reading-from-rs-232-port-using-python)

Comment: @KenLee Yes, that's probably how I would do it. The application could have a build-in web server that can be easily accessed from the browser. Actually, that is how I have solved this problem in the past.

Answer (score 0):

Searching on Packagist you can find some package which allows *serial communication*, anyway not all of them run in Windows environment. Otherwise you can try to install PHP library [dio](https://pecl.php.net/package/dio)